# multiple values insert to mysql using last used id for multiple files

Tags: php, mysql, file, user-input

i'm making a car info form in the admin panel. I want to add 6 images which would have the same id as the car info

```
form
  car info selectors (x12)
  file input (x6)
/form
```

2 separate tables (cars and images)

how do i give all the file inputs the same id as the car info? 
i'm new to programming, but in my mind i have to use max(id) from the car table, add +1 and give it to all the input files carID when inserting them to the database. Is there and easier way to do this? or is my logic faulty?

Comment: 2 separate dbs or 2 separate tables?

Comment: tables :) sry for mislead :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli in php then use the mysqli_insert_id function

http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

This gives you the id of the last record inserted.

You should never just use the max id. Entirely possible another record has been inserted by another user / process between your insert and you following inserts of dependent records.